# Cordova Sticky/Permanent Notification Icon

Tags: cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins

I am using Cordova,I want to set my app icon in the status bar on an event(Which can not be cleared).

In native android by setting FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT and FLAG_NO_CLEAR flags. I hope this can be achieved.
Is there any available plugin for this in Cordova.

For Native: I could achieve it by

```
public void showIcon(String color){
    NotificationManager NM=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     NotificationCompat.Builder nb= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
     nb.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
     nb.setContentTitle("Stick");
     if(color.equals("green"))
         nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.green);
     else
         nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.red);
     Notification notification = nb.build();
     notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
     notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
     NM.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Please find the below images

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this? https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

I don't know if it can do the sticky/no clear part though.